# Matrix relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $3\times6$ and $6\times12$ matrices respectively in the following form.

$$
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccccc}
   a_{11} & a_{12}&0&0&0&0 \\
   0&0&a_{23} & a_{24}&0&0 \\
   0&0&0&0&a_{35}&a_{36}
  \end{array} } \right],
$$

$$
   B=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
   a_{11} & a_{12}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
   0&0&a_{11} & a_{12}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
   0&0&0&0&a_{23} & a_{24}&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
   0&0&0&0&0&0&a_{23} & a_{24}&0&0&0&0 \\
   0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&a_{35}&a_{36}&0&0\\
 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&a_{35}&a_{36}
 \end{array} } \right],
$$

Is there any way to write $B$ as a linear combination of matrix $A$??

Comment: By that I mean are there any matrix $X$ and $Y$ with $6\times3$ and $6\times12$ order respectively such that $B=YAX$? Or any other form?

Answer (score 1):

Note that writing $B$ as a linear combination of some set of matrices $\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$ means to write $B = \alpha_1A_1+\cdots+\alpha_nA_n$ for some scalars $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$. In this context, the matrix $B$ would need to be the same size as the matrices $A_1, \ldots, A_n$. So, saying that $B = XAY$ is writing $B$ as a linear combination of $A$ is a misuse of the term linear combination.

---

Suppose $B = XAY$ for some matrices $X \in \mathbb{R}^{6 \times 3}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{6 \times 12}$.

Then, $\text{rank}(B) = \text{rank}(XAY) \le \min(\text{rank}(X),\text{rank}(A),\text{rank}(Y)) \le \text{rank}(A) \le 3$.

However, if $a_{11},a_{12},a_{23},a_{24},a_{35},a_{36}$ are all non-zero, then $\text{rank}(B) = 6$.

Hence, there are no matrices $X \in \mathbb{R}^{6 \times 3}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{6 \times 12}$ such that $B = XAY$ for all values of $a_{11},a_{12},a_{23},a_{24},a_{35},a_{36}$.

---

Since you also asked if we could write $B$ in any other form:

Let $X_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $Y_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$,

and $X_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, $Y_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Then, we can write $B = X_1AY_1+X_2AY_2$.